# Force browser to use cached JS files

Tags: javascript, caching, browser

I'm loading a series of js files via XMLHttpRequest, and I noticed that even with caching it's making a call to the server, which replies with a 304 message. I would like to know how to prevent the browser from even checking if the file is out of date and directly grab the js from the cache (like it currently does with images). I have found a lot of information online about cache-busting but not much about the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to roll your own proprietary solution. There is more detail in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104265/caching-a-jquery-ajax-response-in-javascript-browser)