# jquery default caching is not working :(

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, caching, http-headers

I have set `cache:true` in my jquery get service request. But this is not working. When i run the fiddler parallel, everytime my url is being hit rather than response fetched  from cache. How do I test my data is fetched from cache. I believe using fiddler is the correct approach to test? Any pointers will be really helpful to me. Also I have noted down in my http headers it always send the below two parameters though I have set as `cache:true`

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Pragma:no-cache
```

But my http response headers which is comes from server is not having these above two http attributes.

CodePen : http://codepen.io/selvaonline/pen/gpyLRz

Comment: Please show code used. You have a typo in question for `cahce:true` .. should be `cache:true`

Comment: Can you share your code. Meantime try reading this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104265/caching-a-jquery-ajax-response-in-javascript-browser

Comment: Make sure you don't have `Rules->Performance->Disable Caching` checked in fiddler

Comment: Really not clear enough what is going on with just a snipped of header information...where's the code used? I suspect this is a confusion of what ajax cache means

Comment: @charlietfl,@anam i have created a codepen http://codepen.io/selvaonline/pen/gpyLRz by following the stackoverflow example but still it is not working. Can you please help?

Comment: @CupawnTae I have checked and i don't have any Disable Cache enabled on my fiddler settings

Comment: What exactly are your expectations? The actual problem has not been clearly identified. Also demo didn't event include jQuery and throws error.

Comment: i want to cache my ajax response for 1 minute, if user click the button before one minute the url should not get fired and the response should get it from the cache. thats it.

Comment: @charlietfl i have created other simple jquery via codepen, even that is not working. Can you please help? http://codepen.io/selvaonline/pen/gpyLej

Comment: Store time of last request. Store response data. If time less than one minute use local data, if not make new request and store it and update time. Shouldn't be complicated

Comment: @charlietfl Can i use the browser cache instead of this local cache?https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching?csw=1#LeverageBrowserCaching. What is the advantage and disadvantage?

Comment: No, not really. Different use case