# Jquery Ajax response Caching

Tags: jquery, browser-cache, jquery-ajaxq

I am trying to cache the jQuery Ajax response. The response headers are as below
But the data is not getting cache each time it is requesting back to server.

[image]

I have gone though the link 
1. [Caching a jquery ajax response in javascript/browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104265/caching-a-jquery-ajax-response-in-javascript-browser)
and few other my jquery call is like below

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "xxx",
                type: "POST",
                data: { 'xxx':'XXX'},
                asyn: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data)...
```

but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like POST responses are not cached. From [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#options):

> The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.

Also, see this:

[Caching a jquery ajax response in javascript/browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104265/caching-a-jquery-ajax-response-in-javascript-browser)