# JqxGrid Virtual scrolling and pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, jqxgrid, virtualscroll

As the user scrolls up, in this scenario  should request go again and get new data or it shows previously loaded data?

In my case every time a new request has gone to the server. How I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a cache layer between Scroller and Network adapter. This can be done with the framework API near the Network (all the frameworks you mentioned in the tag list have such API: [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117653/cache-an-http-get-service-response-in-angularjs), [angular](https://blog.logrocket.com/caching-with-httpinterceptor-in-angular/), [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104265/caching-a-jquery-ajax-response-in-javascript-browser)). Or you can implement caching alongside the Scroller, but this is highly dependent on the Scroller implementation and the App-Scroller integration. In two words, you need to cache a response by its request params, and if params of some request match the cached ones, use cached response (otherwise, perform the request and cache its response).